# Convert Negative number to floating point

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

```
let inputArr = [5,-4,9,-6,7]; 
//expected output is 975.46
```

I have unsorted array that contains both positive and negative values. Expected output should be descending order of number and negative values should come after dot(.) like floating points. In above example -4 and -6 should come after dot(.) and I am able to achieve array descending sorting but not able to convert negative number as floating point value.

```
let inputArr = [5,-4,9,-6,7];
let output = inputArr.sort((a,b)=> b-a).join('') 
//output is 975-4-6
```

Comment: what about zeroes?

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace `-` as you need in your code.

```js
let inputArr = [5,-4,9,-6,7];
let output = inputArr.sort((a,b)=> b-a).join('').replace('-', '.').replaceAll('-', '')

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Find the `negativeIndex` using [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).
- `Slice` the array `positive` on one side and `negative` on another.
- `join` both the array.

```js
let inputArr = [5, -4, 9, -6, 7];
const sorted = inputArr.sort((a, b) => b - a);
const negativeIndex = sorted.findIndex((a) => a < 0);
const positive = sorted.slice(0, negativeIndex).join("");

const negative = sorted
  .slice(negativeIndex)
  .map((x) => x * -1)
  .join("");

const result = `${positive}.${negative}`;
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort by sign and join and replace with a counter.

```js
const
    array = [5, -4, 9, -6, 7],
    result = array
        .sort((a, b) => b - a)
        .join('')
        .replace(/-/g, (i => _ => i++ ? '' : '.')(0))

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would also work

```js
let inputArr = [5,-4,9,-6,7];
inputArr.sort((a, b) => b - a);

let output = "";
let passed = false;
inputArr.forEach(num => {
    if (num >= 0) {
        output += num;
    } else if (!passed) {
        output += `.${-num}`;
        passed = true;
    } else {
        output += -num;
    }
});
console.log(output);
```